# accessing WCF web service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-services

I created a service in WCF and published it to the IIS server via FTP.

When I add a service reference to the WPF program that will be using it I get there was no service found at the given url.

When I navigate to the location on the IIS server to view errors I get the following

> Service has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

I'm referencing it by using

```
https://site/folder/MyService.svc
```

What might I be missing here?

***added web.config***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but did you actually read the error message?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand it, this is my first stab at using WCF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not giving us much to go on....

The error says clearly: the service on your server doesn't define any service endpoints - no endpoints, no connection.

You'll need to check your server-side `web.config` file.

Do you have a `<system.serviceModel> / <services> / <service>`  node in there? What does it say? Could you possibly update your original question and show us the server-side `web.config` (the `<system.serviceModel>` section of it)

A common mistake is that the `<service name="...." />` attribute **must exactly match** the **fully-qualified class name** (class name including namespace) of the class that actually implements your service contract - the **concrete** class (not the interface!) that actually contains the service code.

**Update:**

a typical / minimal `<service>` tag might look like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service name="NameSpace.YourServiceImplementationClass>
          <endpoint name="DefaultEndpoint"
              address=""   -- no need to specify if you're hosting in IIS
              binding="basicHttpBinding"   -- defines the protocol to use to talk to your endpoint
              contract="NameSpace.IYourServiceContract" />
      </service> 
   </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Of course, you can add more configuration as needed - you'll need to pick the **binding** as your first step - how (using what protocol and what settings) are your clients going to talk to your service?

Comment: I don't have a <service> section so I guess that is my issue. I'll have to look it up and see what it should look like unless you could provide a sample

Comment: Thanks this helped. Had to do some other things for https but it's working now. Whats the best way to hide access from the web but still allow my client to access the services? When I point to it in a browser it shows the link with ?wsdl and how to create the class to work with. I want to hide this and generate the wsdl to place in my application rather then being able to add the reference from the internet. Hope that made sense.

Comment: @Tsukasa: to avoid your service from being "discovered", just don't expose the metadata and the WSDL - as shown above. You can turn on metadata (a so-called "MEX" endpoint) and you can make the WSDL describing the service accessible by `(yourUrl)?wsdl` - but those need to be explicitly turned on to work